# How to find all entities with Spring Data where title contains all provided values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, search

I'm working on search algorithm right now and I'm curious if there is any construction in Sprint Data JPA where I can do like so:

```
List<NewsNote> repisitory.findAllByTitleContainsAll(Set<String> keys);
```

Currently, I found only construction for a single element.

Thank you

Comment: Try with repisitory.findByTitleContaining(Set<String> keys)

Comment: @Alien no, friend it doesn't work. I tried already

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Data JPA supports multiple out of the box queries without the need to specify the JPQL. For what you intend, you should define a new method in your repository like this:

```
findByTitleIn(Collection<String> keys)
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) to know which queries you can create from method names.

Comment: Doesn't work too. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to do build a native query as the amount of keys may vary.
Simple Select and StringBuilder works fine.